# algorithms for high dimensional data in a small sample size

Tags: machine-learning, small-sample, high-dimensional

I am trying to analysis high-dimensional data in a small sample size and I meet a problem: 
First,I divided all samples into two sets: training set and test set. 
Second, in the training set The Y is 500*1 matrix and the X is 500*90000 matrix, I use the method of plsr to regression X on Y. Using LOO method, I can get the best plsr model. And i use this model to predict 100 samples in test sets. The variance of predicted Y is small and the value of predicted Y are centering on the mean.
I tried many regression method, there was always this problem. Can someone tell me why and how to deal with this?